# M-RET behave differently in org mode 8.0.3

Tags: emacs, org-mode

My emacs version is GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) of 2013-03-18 on MARVIN.

If I start emacs with '-q' option, I'll use the built-in org-mode 7.9.3f, and for following text

```
* Level 1
** Level 2
   Some text for level2.
```

if I press M-RET at the end of the last line, I'll get a new heading in a new line.

```
* Level 1
** Level 2
   Some text for level2.
**
```

However, in org mode 8.0.3(from ELPA), it makes the last line a new heading instead of inserting a new one.

```
* Level 1
** Level 2
** Some text for level2.
```

It's very intrusive and I'm wondering whether it's a bug or something. Could you tell me how to get M-RET behave like version 7.9.3f?

Comment: Can't reproduce with org-mode 8.0.2. When using different versions of org-mode, likely they conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known new behavior which was introduced just recently and a possible bug, see

- http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/72172
- http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/72399