# M-RET to make text into same-level headline in org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

In org-mode < 8 M-RET at the beginning of non-headline text will make that text into a headline with the same level as the one above.

Example:

```
* Headline
Text
```

If the cursor is in the beginning of 'Text' then `M-RET` will produce:

```
* Headline
* Text
```

In org-mode > 8 this behavior has changed. The same action will produce:

```
* Headline
* 
Text
```

What would be a way to easily make text into a headline like in the < 8 versions of org-mode?

(C-* comes close but will produce a headline one level below the above:

```
* Headline
** Text
```

)

(NB: It isn't the same as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088264/m-ret-behave-differently-in-org-mode-8-0-3) which I guess has been fixed. Anyways I'm not getting that in org-mode 8.2.5h-dist)

Answer (score 0):

`M-RET`runs `org-meta-return`in my old `org-mode`. And according to the docs that runs `org-insert-heading`. You could perhaps try that command or have a look at the code for it.